# Knockout bind data to text box on button click

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I am new to Knockout. i am trying to get the value of a text box,click a button and using REST, get some data from SharePoint and update it on another text box, I am able to get the data but unable to bind it to the text box. Please help. i am just trying to display the account name in the firstname text box

here is my code so far:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/crdrdev/SiteAssets/JS/Knockout/knockout-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/crdrdev/SiteAssets/JS/JQuery/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/crdrdev/SiteAssets/JS/Request%20Controller/RequestController.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/crdrdev/SiteAssets/JS/Main/test.js"></script>
    <div id="custom-new-form">
       <fieldset>
         <legend>Sales Return Approval</legend>
           <div class="left-panel">
             <div class="form-field">
               <div class="field-label">
                 <span>ID:</span>
                    <span class="ms-formvalidation" title="This is a required field."> *</span>
               </div>
             <div class="field-value">
                <input class="single-text-input" type="text" data-bind="textInput: newISID().ISID" id="ISID"/>
                <br/>
                <!--<div class="ms-formvalidation validation-message" data-bind="visible: ISIDValidator">
                    <span role="alert">You must specify a value for this required field.</span>
                </div>-->
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="button" id="btnGetUserProperties" value="Go!" data-bind="click: getUserProperties">
        <div class="form-field">
            <div class="field-label">
                <span>First Name:</span>
                <span class="ms-formvalidation" title="This is a required field."> *</span>
            </div>
            <div class="field-value">
                <input class="single-text-input" type="text" data-bind="value:firstName"/>
                <br/>
                <!--<div class="ms-formvalidation validation-message" data-bind="visible: fstNameValidator">
                    <span role="alert">You must specify a value for this required field.</span>
                </div>-->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
</div>

 function getISID()
 {
    var self=this;
    self.isid=ko.observable();
 }
 function item(data)
 {
    var self=this;
    alert(data);
    var viewModel={firstName:ko.observable(data.d.AccountName)};
 }

 function userViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.newISID= ko.observable(new getISID());
    self.getUserProperties = function () {
    var koisid=ko.toJSON(self.newISID());
    var splitisid=koisid.split(':"')[1];
    var isid=splitisid.replace('"}','')

    var oisid=isid + '@.com';
    var fullisid='i:0%23.f|membership|' + oisid;
    var url="/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor(accountName=@v)?@v="+"'"+fullisid+"'";
    alert(url);
    $.ajax({
            url: someurl,
            method: "GET",
            async: false,
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
            success: function (data) {
                if(data.d.Email=="undefined" || data.d.Email==undefined)
                {
                    alert("Enter correct ISID");
                }
                else
                {                       
                    return new item(data);
                }                   
            },
            failure: function(){
                alert("please enter correct ISID")
            }
    });
}   
}
$(document).ready(function () {
   ko.applyBindings(new userViewModel());
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ajax` call returns a new `item`, but that never goes anywhere. To be able to do `data-bind="value:firstName"`, you need to have a `firstName` member in your viewmodel:

```
self.firstName = ko.observable();
```

Then in your ajax call, assign it:

```
self.firstName(data.d.AccountName);
```

You could create an `item` member and bind `item.firstName` in your view, but I don't see any reason for the additional layer here.

Comment: Roy, I ran into another problem, can you please look at this and give me a suggestion? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48742661/knockout-unable-to-process-binding-in-a-specific-function it would be a huge help, thanks